# Change the storage path in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to change the Laravel 5.1 storage path: something like `/home/test/storage`. This has the advantage that these files are not stored in the repository, which is fairly ugly I think.

In Laravel 4, this was very simple with `bootstrap/paths.php`.

In Laravel 5, it works by using `$app->useStoragePath('/path/')` in `bootstrap/app.php`. However, I want to define the storage path with a config option, like `$app->useStoragePath(config('app.storage_path')`. The config option calls an environment variable or returns a default location.

Doing this results in a `Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class config does not exist'`; this makes sense, because this function is not loaded yet.

I tried setting the storage path just after booting:

```php
$app->booted(function () use ($app) {
    $app->useStoragePath(config('app.storage_root'));
});
```

This changed nothing. I also tried directly binding it to `path.storage`:

```php
$app->bind('path.storage', function ($app) {
    return config('app.storage_root');
});
```

The last option works partially; the view cache is now placed in the correct location, but the logs are still at the old location.

Answer (score 12):

Set it up in .env

app.php

```
'app_storage' => env('APP_STORAGE', storage_path()),
```

app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->useStoragePath(config('app.app_storage'));
}
```

.env

```
APP_STORAGE=custom_location
```

Comment: Not sure why but I got a 'ReflectionException - Class path.storage does not exist' error in register() line '' - way round it was this: 

        if (config('app.app_storage'))
            $this->app->useStoragePath(config('app.app_storage'));

And php artisan config:clear

Answer (score 9):

Laravel 5.3 is in **bootstrap/app.php**

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Set Storage Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This script allows us to override the default storage location used by
| the  application.  You may set the APP_STORAGE environment variable
| in your .env file,  if not set the default location will be used
|
*/

$app->useStoragePath( env( 'APP_STORAGE', base_path() . '/storage' ) );
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple solution of changing the storage path in **Laravel 5** like we do in **Laravel 4**

on bootstrap/app.php

```
# new storage path
# base_path() -> returns root path
$path_storage = base_path() . "../../storage";

# override already $app->storagePath using the function
$app->useStoragePath($path_storage);
```

this will make the storage path to be same with the session, views, cache, logs

Answer (score 2):

This works on Laravel 5.2

File: `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

```
public function register() {
  ...
  $this->app->useStoragePath(config('what_ever_you_want'));
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `useStoragePath` on your `AppServiceProvider` wouldn't do the job properly because the `AppServiceProvider` is called after the config files are loaded. so any use of `storage_path` in config files would still refer to the old storage path.

In order to properly solve this problem I suggest you extend `Application` class and then on the constructor of your own class write the followings.

```
    /**
     * MyApplication constructor.
     */
    public function __construct($basePath = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($basePath);
        // set the storage path
        $this->afterLoadingEnvironment(function () {
            $this->useStoragePath(/*path to your storage directory*/);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if your website is hosted;

move everything from public folder to root folder

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your **bootstrap/app.php** :

```
$app->useStoragePath(__DIR__ . '/../custom-path/');
```

and in **config/filesystem.php** :

```
   'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('everything'), //custom-path/everything
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path(''),
        'url' => env('APP_URL'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

and then run `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 0):

This works on Laravel 5.8 because you have to load the environment variables before you try to use them.

File: bootstrap/app.php

```
$app->afterLoadingEnvironment(function() use ($app) {
    $app->useStoragePath(env('APP_STORAGE', storage_path()));
});
```