# Laravel how to link storage of two websites to the same directory out of the project

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

Support I have two website like bellow:

```
- website1
   - app
   .....
   .....
   - config
   - storage

- website2
   - app
   .....
    .....
   - config
   - storage


- shared_disk
```

I want to store file of both websites in shared_disk and symbolic link it with their storage directory.
Currently I have like this:

```
'disk' => [
    'shared_disk' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => '../../upload',
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],
]
```

And I upload it like this:

```
Storage::disk('shared_disk')->put('file', file_get_contents($request->file('file')));
```

But it does not works and gives following error:

```
Unable to create a directory at ../../shared_link.
```

Comment: Find your answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841392/change-the-storage-path-in-laravel-5

Comment: in config/filesystems.php find local driver config and set path as ``'root' => storage_path('../../shared'),`` also make sure the new folder is created and has proper permissions

Comment: @Sumitkumar That gives me the following error `Unable to create a directory at /var/www/html/storage/../../shared_disk.`